# When merging two contacts in the same campaign with different campaign statuses, which status "wins"?

Tags: campaign-member, merge

When two or more contacts belong to the same campaign and are merged in Salesforce, which campaign status is kept? For instance, contact A is in email subscription 1 with a status of "Subscribed," and contact B is in email subscription 1 with a status of "Resubscribed." We have done testing on this but can't find a clear answer--it does not seem to follow the master account or the last changed status.

We found previous information on this suggesting the following, neither of which bore out in our testing:

1. https://university.zoominfo.com/learn/article/salesforce-surviving-field-values-rules When merging two Salesforce Leads or Contacts and both are associated to a single Salesforce Campaign, but they have different Campaign Member Statuses (i.e. "Invited to Webinar" and "Attended Webinar"). The merged Leads/Contacts will have the Last Modified Member Status. In the example above, "Attended Webinar" is the last member status and will survive in the Lead after merging.
2. https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdnBbUAJ/campaign-member-merging-should-keep-status-other-than-registered the campaign member status that is kept is not based on which contact was selected as master, nor based on the sort order. Instead, the platform seems to choose registered in every case.

Any clues on this?

edited for clarity

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to clarify some confusion - your title refers to Contact merge, but your text refers to Account 1 and Account 2.  Which object are you merging?  Account campaign member is a relatively new feature, but the master status should win.  Have you opened a case with Salesforce?

Comment: My recollection from when I tested this is that the most recently modified campaign member record would be preserved, but I did not do extensive testing.  Curious to see what others find, or if any docs exist.  It may be worth logging a case to try and get an official answer.